# Como obter médias das ocorrências passadas em relação a linha em questão em um dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Estou construindo um modelo preditivo para classificar partidas de futebol, o modelo usa as  médias de  gols na temporada dos times separados entre mandantes e visitantes, estou calculando a média em relação ao ano todo, porém em jogos do começo da temporada preciso considerar apenas os gols feitos até aquela rodada. Logo é necessário fazer o cálculo da média considerando apenas linhas anteriores referentes a temporada em questão. o código está assim:

```
avgMandanteTemporada = df_entradas.groupby(['Mandante','Ano'])['MandanteGols'].mean().reset_index()
avgVisitanteTemporada = df_entradas.groupby(['Visitante','Ano'])['VisitanteGols'].mean().reset_index()
avgGSMandanteTemporada = df_entradas.groupby(['Ano','Mandante'])['VisitanteGols'].mean().reset_index()
avgGSVisitanteTemporada = df_entradas.groupby(['Ano','Visitante'])['MandanteGols'].mean().reset_index()
```

Porém esse código me retorna a média em relação ao ano todo, preciso de uma alternativa que me retorne as médias calculadas até cada rodada.
O dataset está assim:

[image: dataset]

Precisava da média calculada separadamente por rodada, considerando os gols feitos até aquele momento, linhas anteriores que pertencem ao mesmo ano.
Tentei fazer usando .shift() mas não consegui o resultado esperado.

Tentei representar através da imagem a seguir o resultado que estou buscando:

[image: resultado esperado]

o Resultado da  média para  cada  linha deve ser o somatório de todas as linhas anteriores (referentes a temporada em questão) dividido pelo número de rodadas.

o dataset está disponível através do link:
[Link para dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bNemESmmEijuNMWz8AvrVvqvtxo_FwDZ/view?usp=sharing)

obs: Clube 1 = Mandante ; Clube 2 = Visitante

Comment: Podes pf fornecer uma amostra do dados (csv pequeno) ou uma maneira de copiar/colar o dataframe para que seja mais facil testar e ajudar?

Comment: Não tenho maneira de testar mas se resultar diz-me para atualizar uma resposta amanhã, tenta: `df['AvgGF_Mandante'] = df['Mandante'].expanding().mean()`

Comment: Olá Miguel, muito obrigado, usei o .expanding() e acho que obtive os resultados esperados, escrevi o código assim: ```avgMandanteTemporada = df_entradas.groupby(['Mandante','Ano'])['MandanteGols'].expanding().mean().reset_index() ``` editei a publicação e disponibilizei o dataset, estou validando os resultados.

Comment: Os resultados estão de acordo com oque eu esperava exceto por um pequeno detalhe, a média está sendo calculada considerando a linha em questão além de todas as anteriores, eu precisava que fossem consideradas apenas as linhas anteriores.